# Why have supernatural miracles stopped?

Tags: quran, miracles, quranic-events

The Qur'an talks about powerful miracles like splitting the sea, reviving dead people and so on. Do phenomena on this scale happen anymore? (Referring to clearly supernatural events witnessed by large groups of people). If not, is there a reason these types of events only occurred with the Prophets?

Comment: You will have to first prove that there are no miracles at all :). Better ask for miracles' references.

Comment: [What's not right about “Why did all the miracles stoped”?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/862/3487)

Comment: Miracles need not occur only with prophets. A recorded example would be  [Qur'an 3:37](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=3&verse=37).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of miracles if not to make people believe?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14528/what-is-the-purpose-of-miracles-if-not-to-make-people-believe)

Comment: @bjan No, the burden of proof is on the one claiming there are miracles, not the one that rejects that claim.

Answer (score 4):

Miracles came with prophets to prove their prophecy. Islam is a religion for humans. One shouldn't expect miracles to solve his issues. Even the messenger (salla allah alaih w sallam) didn't rely on miracles to spread Islam. That is his Sunnah.

Comment: history of Islam shows messenger of Allah SAWW showed many miracles to people from first day of his prophet-hood. even before his prophet-hood. for example study the history of Badr war.

Comment: True. But in the same time the prophet at no time did rely on miracles. The miracles came from Allah, after he SAWW took all the necessary preparations and reasons to succeed in his mission. Before every war he took maximum precautions, investigations and preparations. That is what he did and that is the Sunnah. Miracles are exceptions to prophets.

Comment: ok so why we people in 2013 have nothing ? all people before got there prophets and there miracles

Comment: @Sidux, You have Quran. You should do some research to find why it is a miracle itself. About your other question, because the earth has an end, the number of prophets is limited too. There must be a last prophet before the end of the world. We were simply born after the last prophet. Asking why we were born after the last prophet is like asking why Gandhi didn't born in 2013.

Comment: @kalahari nearly 1500 years has passed and no world end yet ..., questions  are the essence of all knowledge. If there we need to put limitation to question than every thing can be true.

Comment: @Sidux, So what? 1500 years is nothing compared to the history of mankind. Quran still keeps its originality.

Comment: Miracles can come with any person not only prophets. See example[Qur'an 3:37](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=3&verse=37)

Comment: That's all the difference between islam and chrisitianity. In christianity miracles still occur in the life of believers. @servant-of-Wiser: you make the confusion between  karamah and mu'jizah.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Quran itself is the miracle of our times and contains many scientific miracles. but if one is not aware about the context of society at 1400 years ago in Arabia peninsula when Quran was appeared, it is not easy to understand how Quran is miracle of this era. there are different websites explaining some scientific miracles of Quran.

Another method for seeing miracle is Tawassul. bby Tawassul there is a high possibility that one himself can see a miracle. currently many people are healed miraculously in places like holey shrine of twelve Imams in Iran and Iraq or Medina. for example:

Here is a few examples of Miraculous Healing happening in the holey shrine of Imam Reza a.s. at Mashhad, Iran:

[Miraculous Healing](http://www.imamreza.net/eng/list.php?id=0218)

This list is only few examples (like a drop from an ocean). nearly every Iranian has miraculous experiences from Imam Reza a.s. for himself or his relatives. Iranians love Imam Reza a.s. too much. many of people have seen him in dream that he answers to their questions and problems. this is not only about him but about all of the fourteen infallibles. but because the shrine of 8th Imam is inside Iran and easier to access people of Iran go to his shrine and do Tawassul to him. Tawassul means asking one of Awlia to he ask God to God accept our dua. because our sins make a barrier between us and God and causes our dua do not reach God and so not be accepted. people from all over the world come to holy shrine of Imam Reza a.s. and seek Tawassul from his holy soul.

Example of Tawassul can be seen in many verses of Quran for example:
Children of messenger of God Jacob a.s. could ask God directly but did not and asked their father to he ask God instead of them:

> قَالُوا يَا أَبَانَا اسْتَغْفِرْ‌ لَنَا ذُنُوبَنَا إِنَّا كُنَّا
>   خَاطِئِينَ
>
> They said: "O our father! Ask forgiveness (from Allah) for our sins,
>   indeed we have been sinners." http://tanzil.net/#12:97

And their father did not say this is shirk you should ask God directly. but said:

> قَالَ سَوْفَ أَسْتَغْفِرُ‌ لَكُمْ رَ‌بِّي ۖ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ‌
>   الرَّ‌حِيمُ
>
> He said: "I will ask my Lord for forgiveness for you, verily He! Only
>   He is the Oft-Forgiving, the Most Merciful." http://tanzil.net/#12:98

Another example can be seen in [this verse](http://tanzil.net/#4:64).

Tawassul for healing can be done by belonging of Awlia also. for example see [this verse](http://tanzil.net/#12:93).

This is the process of Tawassul. you yourself can test it and see a miraclt done by any of the fourteen infallibles.

Please note there is two kind of Tawassul. Tawassul can be done only for Awlia. and if it is done to idols or enemies of God it is Shirk. Quran in two verse one prohibite tawassul to idols and in another verse commands using Tawassul to Awlia (i.e. close friends of God specially the fourteen infallibles)

[This is the verse prohibiting Tawassul.](http://tanzil.net/#17:57)

[And this is the verse commanding Tawassul.](http://tanzil.net/#5:35)

Ahl ul Bayt have taught us a special dua that whenever someone needs to do Tawassul to the fourteen infallibles can use this special dua for Tawassul:

[Dua'a E Tawassul  (Seeking Intercession)](http://www.duas.org/tawassul.htm)

Awlia are not dead. although they have left their worldly body. but they are alive and even their worldly body never expire and remains fresh in the grave. they see and hear us everyday and every moment (not by their worldly body. but by their soul). this is said in Quran:

> وَقُلِ اعْمَلُوا فَسَيَرَ‌ى اللَّـهُ عَمَلَكُمْ وَرَ‌سُولُهُ
>   وَالْمُؤْمِنُونَ ۖ وَسَتُرَ‌دُّونَ إِلَىٰ عَالِمِ الْغَيْبِ
>   وَالشَّهَادَةِ فَيُنَبِّئُكُم بِمَا كُنتُمْ تَعْمَلُونَ
>
> And say (O Muhammad SAW) "Do deeds! Allah will see your deeds, and
>   (so will) His Messenger and the believers. And you will be brought
>   back to the All-Knower of the unseen and the seen. Then He will inform
>   you of what you used to do." http://tanzil.net/#9:105

It is clear that usual believers like us can not see the deeds of people. in the different hadith it is said the believers in this verse means the fourteen infallibles and they everyday see deeds of people. another verses says we should not call them dead, but they are alive:

> وَلَا تَحْسَبَنَّ الَّذِينَ قُتِلُوا فِي سَبِيلِ اللَّـهِ أَمْوَاتًا ۚ
>   بَلْ أَحْيَاءٌ عِندَ رَ‌بِّهِمْ يُرْ‌زَقُونَ
>
> Think not of those who are killed in the Way of Allah as dead. Nay,
>   they are alive, with their Lord, and they have provision.
>   http://tanzil.net/#3:169

The has been many tries like fabricating fake hadith by dictators to people do not learn about Tawassul because this is against their power and dictatorship. here is a hadith saying that all of the Ahl ul Bayt are killed or poisoned. they were killed covertly by dictators who wanted to keep power and abuse huge financial income of Islamic states. (Muslims conquered 2/3 of world at a time and huge amounts of golds were income of King) and could not see Ahl ul Bayt get power and establish government by support of believers. for example Imam Hussain a.s. and 72 of his pious companions and his children were killed by attack of a 30,000 soldiers army of Yazid at Karbala.

Anyway the best and easiest possible way of seeing a miracle by your own eyes is doing Tawassul to the Ahl ul Bayt. they are very merciful and answer you very soon. but a serious Tawassul with loving them is needed to they answer soon. leaving sin and obeying obeying them as well as Quran makes acceptance of dua and seeing miracle done by them much more sooner.

At Badr war one Muslim came to prophet SAWW and said I do not have any sword. prophet took a wood in his hand and it became a sword and given it to the man. in immigration from mecca to Mdina prophet SAWW saw an old woman having a goat and said her give us some milk. she said no rain no grass no milk. he touched the goat and the goat had a lot of milk. prophets SAWW and infallible Imams and Awlia have Izn (permission to control nature) from God and even have the ability to create a living thing:

وَرَ‌سُولًا إِلَىٰ بَنِي إِسْرَ‌ائِيلَ أَنِّي قَدْ جِئْتُكُم بِآيَةٍ مِّن رَّ‌بِّكُمْ ۖ أَنِّي أَخْلُقُ لَكُم مِّنَ الطِّينِ كَهَيْئَةِ الطَّيْرِ‌ فَأَنفُخُ فِيهِ فَيَكُونُ طَيْرً‌ا بِإِذْنِ اللَّـهِ ۖ وَأُبْرِ‌ئُ الْأَكْمَهَ وَالْأَبْرَ‌صَ وَأُحْيِي الْمَوْتَىٰ بِإِذْنِ اللَّـهِ ۖ وَأُنَبِّئُكُم بِمَا تَأْكُلُونَ وَمَا تَدَّخِرُ‌ونَ فِي بُيُوتِكُمْ ۚ إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَةً لَّكُمْ إِن كُنتُم مُّؤْمِنِينَ

> And [make him] a messenger to the Children of Israel, [who will say],
>   'Indeed I have come to you with a sign from your Lord in that I design
>   for you from clay [that which is] like the form of a bird, then I
>   breathe into it and it becomes a bird by **permission of Allah**. And I
>   cure the blind and the leper, and I give life to the dead - by
>   permission of Allah. And I inform you of what you eat and what you
>   store in your houses. Indeed in that is a sign for you, if you are
>   believers. http://tanzil.net/#3:49

Indeed the rank of the fourteen infallibles is higher than past prophets.

Usual Muslims also if obey Allah in all aspects of religion and leave all sins and be [pious](http://www.al-islam.org/self-building-ayatullah-ibrahim-amini/characteristics-pious-sermon-hammam) can receive Izn from God. currently such people are living. but they are very rare and unknown. they dislike to be known because disliking being famous is [command of Quran](http://tanzil.net/#28:83) and is part of being pious.

Imam khomeini said the sands were commanded by God to do [this miracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Eagle_Claw). a soldier that was guarding the home of Imam Khomeini said that at the same night that this US operation failed Imam Khomeini woke up for night prayer and for a long time was looking at a direction and finally said thanks to God this was resolved too. the soldier says at morning the news of this happening was published and he found that direction has been the direction to location of this happening.

By using Tawassul one can see the miracle by his own eyes. Tawassul is the best way for seeing a miracle. for example healing of one who doctors can not heal him.

Comment: I see this answer is more geared towards tawasul. More connection should be made as to why tawasul is linked to miracles along with contemporary references which OP tends to be asking for, which frankly seems off-topic on this site. Events of the past should be focused but not centralized. E.g the point where you mention Quran as miracle you should not be focusing solely on how it was a miracle 1400yrs ago but how is it is one in this era. More academics surely is required.

Answer (score 1):

Quran never uses the word *Miracle* for splitting of water [26:63](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.yusufali/26:63), or breathing life in to birds made out of clay [3:49](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.yusufali/3:49). The word used is *Aya* - Sign. For splitting of water, its not even referred to as a sign.

In fact, the Arabic triliteral for "miracle" (Mujizah)(**معجزة**) is never used in that sense throughout the Quran. [Quran Dictionary - ع ج ز](http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=Ejz) [Ejz]. The grammatical meaning of Mujizah is "something that causes Ejz (failure, defeat, surrender)"

Muslims believe that Prophets were given great signs, sometimes as last measures, to help deliver the message. Furthermore, the signs provided for specifically that purpose are believed to be supernatural and therefore miraculous. Breathing life into clay-birds and a she-camel coming out of mountain are a couple of examples. As for events of supernatural value that were not produced as signs, a more appropriate word is [Keramah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keramat) (**کرامة**). In common usage, the two words are used interchangeably with one difference that a prophetic Keramah is almost always referred to as a miracle. [Israr Ahmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israr_Ahmed) was a notable contemporary scholar to have highlighted such subtle differences.

Once the difference between Mujizah (miracle) and Keramah is in place, it is easy to say that miracles, by virtue of being given to prophets only as signs, do not happen anymore. Keramah, however, it is believed it can still be produced by *Auliya* (saints). This belief, however, is not equally shared by all Muslims and Salafis, for example, generally reject the whole province of Sufism.

To wrap it up, the word miracle is used both in specific theological meanings as well as just a synonym for "supernatural."

Answer (score 0):

## It's more like we stopped seeing them.

This world and everything within is a sign of God, don't wait just for splitting of moon to be sure that there is a god,

- Quran is considered a miracle, just listen to what native Arabic speakers say about it and how people came to believe in Islam just by reading it.
- Many of the laws of Physics which guarantee continuation of our life are just so miraculously there, it's just needs us to see more clearly! Look at for example at exceptional characteristics of water(unlike any other material on earth) and how any of them were not there life would be impossible.
- Just for example consider your eye and how it tells your mind about rays of light and their wave length so that your mind can interpret those messages into such exact pictures, Can you really believe such thing happens by putting some materials beside each other and then waiting any length of time??
- As [Battle of karbala](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/10275/4710) said: Many supernatural events happen even now by the will of Allah. Even for us when we make dua's and .. just look closer at events happening for you in your life.
- ...
- And more than anything our existence, this world and anything; **all from nothing** is the biggest miracle ever. just ask "Why there are all these things??" instead of nothing.

But the reason supernatural events took place only in prophets time like splitting moon, and why it's not happening now so everyone would believe! I guess in that time it was necessary for people of that time, but now I think due to the science vision of our time that everything that happens is normal, many miracles happen everyday but everyone just says it's normal,

> Even if We sent down angels to them, and caused the dead to speak to them, and We gathered together everything in front of them, they would still not believe, unless God had so willed. But most of them behave ignorantly. ([6/111](http://tanzil.net/?locale=en_IN#6:111))

---

Our belief is the sole purpose of us being here! It is not a test in the first place if we were confronted with angels or ...!!

> Are they waiting for the angels or your Lord to come down to them, or for some of your Lord's signs to come? The day when some of the signs of your Lord shall come, it shall not profit any human being who did not believe before, or who did not do any good by his faith. Say to them, "Wait then, we too are waiting." ([6/158](http://tanzil.net/?locale=en_IN#6:158))

Comment: 1) the bible and Bhagavad Gita are miracles by that logic 2) physics is scientific and natural, the exact opposite of supernatural 3) The eye has been evolved serperately in 40 mutually uncontact species, it's not miraculous at all. 4) That's the post hoc ergo proper hoc fallacy 5) no1 mentioned "nothing"

Comment: if simple humans coming from nothing can't be possible so how a super advanced being like god came from nothing ? this reflexion is just pushing the issue to an other level.

Comment: The beginning and time are concepts necessary for this materialistic world, where being from nothing or this advance form of us is impossible all by itself.
God is not bound to the concepts of the world he created himself, There is no time or beginning for him.

Comment: @Bludream i understand your point of view, but this logic can make everything true, because we have no basics,if god can't be understood than everything can be god every religion can be true to ...

Comment: @Sidux, could you elaborate more, because this is what I've been thinking about lately so much. I like to know more. tanx

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX, yeah you're right about eye! But your universal rule is incorrect where only humans ended up with thought.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX, and you need to explain why scientists can't create even a single cell by putting together some materials and preparing the right conditions?????

Comment: Humans lived in the right conditions to develop thought, stemming from out biped walking, first known to happen in Homo-Erectus: the "upright man", who's hands were now free to use. Opposing thumbs developed, and eventually using tools was one of our best survival mechanisms. We developed intelligence from it's necessity for our survival. It's our ONLY advantage. We're slow runners, small, short, can't fly, breathe underwater, don't have claws, camouflage, thick insulating skin, our senses like sight, smell and hearing are TERRIBLE compared to other animals, etc.

Comment: Because humans don't have access to the time scale necessary for such a low-chance event. There is some progress in that department though, such as the Miller–Urey experiment, which demonstrated the creation of amino acids and proteans from just basic compounds (water (H2O), methane (CH4), ammonia (NH3), and hydrogen (H2)) and the energy of simulated lightning strikes. Reply on Hangouts for further discourse

Comment: It's like saying by building rocks so they can also build the whole planet too, @XAleXOwnZX amino acids are soooo basin compared to a living cell able to produce one like itself and try to survive, I don't call it low chance event, I call it impossible

Comment: @Bluedream i do agree with XAleXOwnZX, amino acids aren't that simple they are the basics of life ... to prove exactly thos things we need that the experement needs to stay a lot more time and what's the impossible if time is infinit ? but it's not the real probleme because if god can create life he can create it trought evolution, the probleme is that god that we know is realy in the image of a human: he needs to create, he needs to be known, he needs to show his power, he can be angry... old people invented there own father and other ones used it to control others.

Answer (score 0):

**In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Merciful**

**All praise is due to God (ﷻ), the Lord of the Worlds. The Beneficent, the Merciful. Master of the Day of Judgement, and God’s Peace and Blessings be upon Muhammad (ﷺ), his family, his noble Companions, and all those who follow them.**

God Says:

> ”And nothing has prevented Us from sending signs except that the former peoples denied them. And We gave Thamud the she-camel as a visible sign, but they wronged her. And We send not the signs except as a warning.” **(17:59, al Isra)** https://quran.com/17/58?translations=20

As you can understand from this verse, the miracles were sent to frighten the disbelievers and rejectors and after the Age of Prophets and Messengers is closed no more miracles as you described.

As you know, God sent the Prophets and Messengers primarily to guide humankind.  They were humans, of outstanding character, pious and trustworthy, that the people could emulate and look to for direction. They were not gods, demi-gods or saints with divine qualities, rather they were mere mortals charged with a difficult task. They possessed exceptional characteristics because they were obligated to face extraordinary trials and tribulations in order to spread the message to worship God Alone. As God Says:

> ”And I (God) created not the jinn and mankind except that they should worship Me (Alone)”.  **Quran 51:56)**

And also, after Muhammad is dead, no more supernatural miracles as you described. Here’s a Hadith about that.

> Anas bin Malik narrated:
>
> The Messenger of God (s.a.w) said: 'Indeed Messenger-ship and Prophethood have been terminated, so there shall be no Messenger after me, nor a Prophet.'" He(Anas) said:"The people were concerned about that, so he (s.a.w) said: 'But there will be Mubash-shirat.' So they said: 'O Messenger of God! What is Mubash-shirat?' He said: 'The Muslim's dreams, for it is a portion of the portions of Prophethood. [**SUNNAH.COM**](https://sunnah.com/urn/675760)

**CONCLUSION:** The reason to why miracles have stopped, is because at the Age of Prophets and Messengers, they were given miracles so that they can call their people to worship one God and avoid to worship the false gods and, when prophet Muhammad came, the last miracle is Quran and now we have Quran and therefor, Quran is our guidance, and miracles were given to only prophets and messengers and today there is no more prophets and messengers, and that’s why supernatural miracles have come to an end.

For more informations about this, check the following sites:

1. [**islamreligion.com**](https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/5291/what-is-miracle/)
2. [**darulfatwa.org.au**](http://www.darulfatwa.org.au/en/the-miracles-of-the-prophets/)
3. [**islamweb.net**](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/175671/miracles-of-the-prophets-of-islam)