# What is the purpose of miracles if not to make people believe?

Tags: quran, allah, belief, miracles

In Holy Quran we read:

> [And they say, "Why was there not sent down to him an angel?" But if We had sent down an angel, the matter would have been decided; then they would not be reprieved.](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/6:8)

This Aya confuses me about if such a miracle would result in all people believe in God and therefore "the matter would have been **decided**, they would not be reprieved". And my assumption that such a belief would be of no value since

> [Are they waiting for the angels or your Lord to come down to them, or for some of your Lord's signs to come? The day when some of the signs of your Lord shall come, **it shall not profit any human being who did not believe before, or who did not do any good by his faith**. Say to them, "Wait then, we too are waiting.](http://tanzil.net/?locale=en_IN#trans/en.wahiduddin/6:158)

My question is then why prophet had miracles like splitting moon or Quran or ... which made many people come to believe in God?? how is this type of belief explained and if they were done for another purpose of forcing people into having faith then what was that purpose??

Comment: I personally always first check Tafseer Al-Mizan by Allame Tabatabee for the meaning and implications of the verses before trying to interpret them on my own!

Comment: OK I'll take a look, but the matter seems clear enough. My point is not about the verses though, you agree with that people believing on miracle is of no value?

Comment: I believe both miracles and individual intellect can be regarded as sources of affirmation of Prophets. But miracles are not readily available to all people in all times while everyone can exercise his intellect to acknowledge Prophet's teachings.

Comment: @Bludream, Can you give the numbers of verses please?

Comment: @kalahari, just click on them

Answer (score 1):

A very cool question...Worth pondering...

Your question has something to deal with the extent of the miracles/signs themselves.

A similar example to add to your two verses i.e. 6:8 and 6:158, is [4:153](http://quran.com/4/153)

> The people of the Scripture (Jews) ask you to cause a book to descend upon them from heaven. Indeed they asked Musa (Moses) for even greater than that, when they said: "**Show us Allah in public,**" but they were struck with thunder clap and lightning for their wickedness. Then they worshipped the calf even after clear proofs, evidences, and signs had come to them. (Even) so We forgave them. And We gave Musa (Moses) a clear proof of authority. (Qur'an 4:153)

I think this could be a better example than which u used.

So, as clearly we can see, there lies difference in extent of miracles. Another counter example along with splitting of Moon etc. is Qur'an [3:49](http://quran.com/3/49)

Now carefully understanding the above cases, we can see that Allah **showed miracles to us** to help us increase our faith in him, not angels or any divinely things nor he himself showed up to prove to humans that God exists.

Thereby the verses hold the reasons of 6:8 and 6:158 valid and crisp without any problem.

May the creator guide us all

Comment: A correction, Allah sent angels as essential messengers at many instances. Just as an example, during wars at the time of Prophet Muhammad(Surah Taubah).

Answer (score 0):

The ayats that you have referred to, refer to the signs before the Judgement Day, not to the miracles that prophets perform.

This world is a test, as long as the hidden things in the world are hidden. Only then we have to use our intellect to reach to the truth. When these things are perceived by our senses, then there is no choice but to believe, so believing after that will not be of any use.

Islam does not rely on miracles to prove his basic premise i.e. God is one and one day you have to confront him and held responsible for your deeds. Allah encourages us to use our observation and intellect to reach to him.

Comment: My belief too, my problem is that if `we have to use our intellect to reach to the truth` why there are miracles too?? and what about those who were forced to believe after seeing miracles?

Comment: Not all people are at the same level of intellect. They have to see it to believe it. But then there will be thoses who will not believe even if they see it. The miracles given to prophets are one of the signs of their prophethood.

Comment: `They have to see it to believe it`, please if you really believe this to be true update your answer and add, `we have to use our intellect to reach to the truth. (Except those who are at a LOW level of intellect)`

Answer (score 0):

**The previous verse is relevant:**

> or you may say, "If the **Book** had been sent down to us, we would surely have followed its guidance better than they did." There has now come to you clear evidence from your Lord, and guidance and mercy. Who, then, is more unjust than one who rejects the **signs** of God and turns away from them? We shall requite those who turn away from Our signs with a painful punishment, for their turning away. (157)

Note, aya means sign, ayat means signs. Allah (swt) says that the ayat have arrived, the signs have arrived, what else are the rejectors expecting? If they did not and do not believe the signs that have arrived already, then anymore signs will be useless.

**This is related too:**

> [“This day, I have perfected your Deen for you, completed My Favor upon you, and have chosen for you Islam as your Deen.”   (Surah Al-Ma'idah, 5:3)](http://quran.com/5/3)

Islam is complete, Quran is complete, all guidance required is there. There were signs for people in the Quran 1,400 years ago, and 1,400 years later there are still signs that attract people towards it. The guidance, information, facts, everything you need to know, information that leads you to success in this life and akhira (afterlife), all of that information is available in the Quran.

If Allah (swt) revealed Angels to us, what difference would it make? The rejectors will probably begin to worship the Angels like they are worshiping Jesus.

Why did the prophet then come with miracles? The prophet's didn't come with miracles to compel people, rather to test who believes and who doesn't after compelling signs have arrived. There are many historical events mentioned in the Quran, where the people have rejected prophets, so miracles aren't suppose to compel people, but to test people.

This life after all is a test, and what is the point of a "judgement day" if there is nothing to judge you by.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer would be - **It is Allah's wish.**

> *But they say, "Why are not signs sent down to him from his Lord?" Say, "**The signs are only with Allah** , and I am only a clear warner." [Qur'an [29:50]](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=29&verse=50)*

It's God's wish to help someone increase in Iman (faith), he would simply provide a miracle / sign / or just coincidence. A believing person considers it as a miracle and tries to increase in faith, while a disbelieving person simply provides explanations. God knows better whom to provide miracles and whom to leave unguided irrespective of whether they demanded it or not.

Allah knows the best.

Answer (score -1):

We overlook the greatest miracle - that we are here and able to ask the meaning of miracles. What is the purpose and meaning of each life? Of your life?
There may be a clue at both ends of the books - Allah wished to hang out with Adam and Eve in the Garden - and created the universe for his relationship with Muhammad pbuh.
Does Allah desire belief? Or does Allah desire relationship? Is the purpose of miracles to produce belief? Or is the purpose of belief to provide friends for Allah? 
Intellect is indeed important, but the heart must be involved as well.

Comment: I'm totally sorry, but I can't get anything from this.  Would you please clarify your answer more?